# Is there a way to refactor multiple assignments after None type checking?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm checking for any not-None class variables in my python code for a PUT request but this includes manually writing many statements, assigning *db_book*  fetched from the database values of  *book*  variables. Can I write this code more concisely?

```
def books_put(db: Session, db_book: schemas.Book, book: schemas.BookPut):

    if book.name is not None:
        db_book.name = book.name

    if book.pages is not None:
        db_book.pages = book.pages

    if book.author is not None:
        db_book.author = book.author

    if book.genre is not None:
        db_book.genre = book.genre

    if book.publishing_house is not None:
        db_book.publishing_house = book.publishing_house
...
```

Comment: Related: [_PEP 505 – None-aware operators_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/)

Comment: What is e.g. `db_book.name` going to be if `book.name` is `None`?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of an easy way to avoid the `if` statement, but you can get rid of all the duplication using a loop.

```
for attr in ['name', 'pages', 'author', 'genre', 'publishing_house']:
    if getattr(book, attr) is not None:
        setattr(db_book, attr, getattr(book, attr))
```

Comment: nit: I'd use a set for the collection, as 1. it might even be faster and 2. order doesn't matter. Else a tuple.

Comment: @2e0byo sets are not faster to iterate than lists or tuples.

Comment: I don't really think the datatype matters for this. Sets are faster for existence tests, I don't see why they would be faster for iteration. And lists or tuples are the fastest to create, since there's no hashing. @2e0byo

Comment: @Barmar  'might' was motivated by never having tested it or cared.  Makes sense it's no faster for iteration. It definitely doesn't matter, but it signals that order doesn't encode anything.  Unless it does, in which case a tuple signals that this is const... but it's a complete nit-pick/style choice.